# Save additional data while creating new role with Yii Rights Module

Tags: php, yii

I have Yii Rights Module http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/

What I want is to save additional data i.e id of the user who created the role in authItem table while creating the role. By going through code I found that following line in AuthItemController.php can help me

```
// Create the item
$item = $this->_authorizer->createAuthItem($formModel->name, $type, $formModel->description, $formModel->bizRule, $formModel->data);
```

I don't get how to store additional data with this code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with some more workaround I found the solution.

I created new field created_by in **authitem** table.

added this function in **RAuthItemBehavior.php**

```
/**
     * add the id of user - who created the role - in db
     * @return doesn't return anything
     */
    public function addItemCreator()
    {
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->update('authitem', array(
            'created_by'=>Yii::app()->user->id,
        ), 'name=:name', array(':name'=>$this->owner->name));
    }
```

and called that function on **AuthItemController.php** in create action by adding this line

```
$item->addItemCreator();
```

after

```
$item = $this->_authorizer->attachAuthItemBehavior($item);
```

any suggestions for improvement are welcomed.